# UITableView com UITableViewCell customizada e redimensionável

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Estou criando um chat para IOs em Objective C, e utilizo UItableViewCell customizada. Minha dificuldade é em redimensionar a Cell conforme o texto nas conversar, como a imagem:

[image: Imagem exemplo do chat]

E essa segunda tela, é de como esta, com uma conversa, sobrepondo a outra, sem ter um limite de quando passara de uma cell para a outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei utilizar a partir de Auto Layout, e não funcionou também. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Não entendi o problema. tem como mandar um print como devia ser?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa a imagem a cima é como deveria estar, que seria o background e a cell sendo redimensionavel através da quantidade de texto, porém não consigo redimensionar a cell, e assim o texto não aparece inteiro.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa inseri um print de como esta no momento.

Comment: Em todas as versões do IOS acontece isso?

Comment: Esse cara aqui teve um problema igual o seu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527227/uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-height-ios

Comment: @PauloHDSousa estou utilizando na versão 9.0, porém creio que sim, pois não mexi em nada que redimensiona a cell, pois não sei, apenas esta separando pelo tamanho da cell fixa na hora em que criei a view separada

Comment: @PauloHDSousa vou dar uma olhada no problema dele.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei sobre tutoriais sobre o mesmo assunto, acho que o site do raywenderlich se encaixa bem no que você quer.
[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975)

A titulo de curiosidade não sei se isso poderia ajudar, mas procurei por bibliotecas de terceiros que teriam até coisas a mais do que acho que você precisa. Vai ai alguns links:

[SPHChatCollectionView](https://github.com/sibahota059/SPHChatCollectionView)

[SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController)

[whatsapp-ios](https://github.com/rcmcastro/whatsapp-ios)

[SOMessaging](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada em todo material que você me passou, desde já, obrigado pela ajuda.